# уезжает вниз внутренний блок при добавлении параграфов

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь создать что-то похожее на шахматную доску,где слева/справа были бы цифры,внизу/вверху буквы. Для этого создал внешний блок, в который засунул блок с шахматной доской.Получилось это вот так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляю слева параграфы с буквами,и внутренний блок уезжает вниз[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите,как это можно исправить.Спасибо

```js
function draw(){
  /*  var main_block=document.querySelector('.main_block');
    var obertka = document.querySelector('.obertka')
    for(i = 0;i< 8; i++){
        
    }
     * 
   */
    var flag=false;
    for( i=0;i<8*8;i++){
        if(i%8==0){
            flag=!flag;
        }
        
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.className = "block";
        if(flag){
            div.classList.add("white");
        }else{
            
            div.classList.add("black");
        }
        flag=!flag;
        main_block.appendChild(div);
    }
    
}

draw();
```

```css
.obertka{
    margin:30px auto;
    width:700px;
    height:700px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.main_block{
  //  position: absolute;
    margin:70px auto;
    width:560px;
    height: 560px;
   
    border:1px solid black;
    
    
}
.block{
    width:70px;
    height: 70px;
    float:left;
}
.black{
    background:black;
}
.white{
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="obertka">
            <p>A</p>
            <p>B</p>
            <div class="main_block">
            
            </div>
        </div>
        
       
        



        <script src="javascript.js"> </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: сделай отдельные блоки для букв\цифр и размести их где нужно, это будет проще

Answer (score 1):

Общий шахматный блок сделал абсолютным и центрированным, вместо маргина. Чтобы он никому больше не мешал. Для этого родительскому блоку еще было добавлено `position: relative`, чтобы удержать внутри абсолютный элемент...

А буквы-числа, через простые блоки... (ну и деревяшка приятно смотрится)

```js
function draw(){

var main_block=document.querySelector('.main_block');
var obertka = document.querySelector('.obertka')

var flag=false;
for( i=0;i<8*8;i++){
    if(i%8==0){
        flag=!flag;
    }

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "block";
    if(flag){
        div.classList.add("white");
    }else{

        div.classList.add("black");
    }
    flag=!flag;
    main_block.appendChild(div);
}

}

draw();
```

```css
/* Добавлено: */

.numbers {
  padding-left: 70px;
  display: flex;
}
.numbers div {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.letters div {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* отметил значками места в коде ниже, где были изменения */

.obertka{
  position: relative; /* ++ */
  background-color: #fff1ba; /* ++ */
  margin:30px auto;
  width:700px;
  height:700px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.main_block{
  position: absolute; /* ++ */
  left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; /* ++ */
  margin: auto; /* ++ */
  width: 560px;
  height: 560px;   
  border:1px solid black;
}
.block{
    width:70px;
    height: 70px;
    float:left;
}
.black{
  background-image: url('https://gyazo.com/242a038b6efca98f8053a191128ccca2.png');
}
.white{
  background-image: url('https://gyazo.com/1bccec18988744ebd73796507594f685.png');
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="obertka">
  <div class="numbers">  
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div> 
    <div>8</div>  
  </div>
  <div class="letters">
    <div>А</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
    <div>D</div>
    <div>E</div>
    <div>F</div>
    <div>G</div> 
    <div>H</div>  
  </div>
  <div class="main_block">

  </div>
</div>

</body>       

</html>
```

Не только тут, но и в целом... если возникает путанница, и что-то работает не так, полезно где-то вверху кода временно добавить `*{ border: 1px solid red !important; }` чтобы было нагляднее, кто-чей родственник и где находится)

Comment: спасибо большое)